# Legend overlaps with donut chart vega

Tags: legend, vega

I'm creating a donut chart using Vega and the legend overlaps the chart despite everything I've tried.

- Using `orient: bottom-right`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPB45.jpg
- I've also tried to finagle the image into the empty space using `legendX, legendY` but the text cuts off.
- Increasing `width` of the specification would work except it auto-centers the visualization, and I'm trying to avoid any more empty space than necessary.

I'm looking for a way to align the chart to the left instead of auto-centering, or anything else you guys can think of. Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set the outerRadius of each arc "slice of pie" in the marks section of the spec.json file, it is divided by width so increasing the default to 2.5 or 3 worked for me.

```
"marks": [
    {
        "type": "arc",
        "from": {
            "data": "table"
        },
        "encode": {
            "enter": {
                "fill": {
                    "scale": "color",
                    "field": "id"
                },
                "x": {
                    "signal": "width / 2"
                },
                "y": {
                    "signal": "height / 2"
                }
            },
            "update": {
                "startAngle": {
                    "field": "startAngle"
                },
                "endAngle": {
                    "field": "endAngle"
                },
                "padAngle": {
                    "signal": "padAngle"
                },
                "innerRadius": {
                    "signal": "width / 4"
                },
                "outerRadius": {
                    "signal": "width / 2.5"
                },
                "cornerRadius": {
                    "signal": "cornerRadius"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```